# Get list of combined neighbors of multiple nodes (2, 3 or more) of graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

Trying to get neighbours of multiple nodes in NetworkX. `G[n]` gives an adjacency dictionary but for single node. `G[n1, n2]` doesn't work and gives KeyError. I want a list of combined neighbors of n1, n2 and so on. The duplicates can be removed by applying a `set()`.

Comment: Can you provide an example graph and the expected output?

Comment: It sounds like you want something like the result of `[k for n in [n1, n2] for k in G[n]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example would help understanding the exact expected output, but you can probably use:

```
target = [0, 1, 3]
out = set().union(*(G.neighbors(n) for n in target))
```

Example:

```
G = nx.lollipop_graph(3, 2)
target = [0, 3]
out = set().union(*(G.neighbors(n) for n in target))
```

output: `{1, 2, 4}`

[image]

Comment: This is the correct output I'm looking for and going to accept this as the solution. I'd request some clarification in terms of performance though of this solution vs `set([k for n in [n1, n2] for k in G[n]])` suggested by @Ben Grossmann

Comment: I guess it's more or less the same. One using a double loop, the other set operations. `set(k for n in target for k in G[n])` could be better than `set([k for n in target for k in G[n]])` though. On the tiny example, the set union is a bit faster. Let us know in your real life example ;)

Comment: For the data that I have, using `time.time()` is not giving same time for every run in jupyter notebook. But all are giving time like 0.00xyz or 0.0. I'll have to learn a bit more to figure this additional bit out but thank you for your useful reply.